# What does 'super.main' mean in Blogger template

Tags: blogger

The main includable contains this code from Blog1 widget -

```
 <b:includable id='main'>
      <!--<b:include name='noContentPlaceholder'/>-->

      <b:comment>Cap the total number of ads (widgets and inline ads).</b:comment>
      <b:with value='3' var='maxNumAds'>
      <b:with value='data:widgets.AdSense.size' var='numDesktopAds'>
      <b:with value='data:widgets.AdSense count (w =&gt; w.sectionId != &quot;ads&quot;)' var='numMobileAds'>
      <b:comment>Filter out the featured post, but only on the homepage.</b:comment>
      <b:with value='data:widgets.FeaturedPost filter (w =&gt; w.sectionId == &quot;page_body&quot;) map (w =&gt; w.postId)' var='featuredPostIds'>
      <b:with value='data:view.isHomepage  ? data:posts filter (post =&gt; post.id not in data:featuredPostIds)   : data:posts' var='posts'>
        <b:include name='super.main'/>
      </b:with>
      </b:with>
      </b:with>
      </b:with>
      </b:with>
    </b:includable>
```

I can understand other tags and expressions used in this code snippet but I cannot figure out what "super.main" means.
When I placed a parent div around the include tag, I realised it nested feed of posts. But which includable does it call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `includable` tag has a default version stored in the Blogger side. `super.main` is the default main tag by Blogger.

Comment: How does it work? What happens when super.main is called in the above case?